# jquery load not executing php function in another file

Tags: php, jquery, function, load

```
//main.php
<?php

include("functions.php");

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
  $("#Div").load("Views/phpfile.php", function(){
   alert("file loaded");
  });
 });
</script>

?>    
//End main.php    

//phpfile.php
<div>dsfg sfdgsdfgsfdgdf</div>
<div>dsfg sfdgsdfgsfdgdf</div>

<?php
 echo sum();
?>
//End phpfile.php
```

while the implementation sum function in inside another file called functions.php notice that if i put the implementation of sum function inside phpfile.php it will work fine.

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: You have to include `functions.php` in `phpfile.php`, not in whatever file the first part of your code is in.

Comment: Ya u are right,but i need to load once in the main file(parent file). Since iam using jquery to load a lot of php files that depend on functions.php so it is not a good idea to include functions.php in these files.

Comment: Well, PHP is executed on the server side. When you load the main file, PHP will process it, generated some output (including your JavaScript) and send the output to the browser. After that, PHP's job is done, until you load another file. But there is not "state" kept between these calls. If the other file also needs to have access to a function defined in `functions.php`, then you have to include the file in there. There is no other way.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation,just i thought that maybe there is a hack for it.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `document.ready` ?

```
$(function(){
    $("#Div").load("Views/phpfile.php", function(){
        alert("file loaded");
    });
})
```

Comment: My code is already as you mention like that:

    $(function(){
        $("#Div").load("Views/phpfile.php", function(){
            alert("file loaded");
        })
    })

 and its loads the content of phpfile.php expecpt the php function for ex: sum()